# How to deploy opencv application into google cloud VM

Tags: python, image, opencv, google-cloud-platform, deployment

I want to deploy my OpenCV application into google cloud. This application is written in python and I need to deploy it into Google Cloud server. It could be run on any os(MAC, Windows, Linux, etc.)
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many options to deploy an application on Google Cloud.

If you developed your application using Python 3.7 or 3.8 you could explore the use of [App Engine Standard](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime) or [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/python-runtime), but in order to have more flexibility and if you used any other versions of Python take a look at [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy#python) or [App Engine Flexible](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/runtime).

If you are not interested in the serverless aspect of Cloud Computing you could simply deploy your application in a [Compute Engine Instance](https://cloud.google.com/python/tutorials/getting-started-on-compute-engine#multiple_instances).